Logging with the possibility of disabling without overhead in C++
I was writing a C++ program, and now I need to benchmark it. For logging I don't want to use a library, since it is an extra dependency (although spdlog is great, for example). I am looking for an elegant and short solution to make the logging lines present or not present based on a parameter.
Checking an if statement can be considered an overhead as well. The nicest thing I could come up with is something like:
#include <iostream>

#define DEBUG

int main()
{
#ifdef DEBUG
    std::cout << "This is a log message" << std::endl;
#endif // DEBUG
}

Wrapping the ifdef-endif in a define is impossible as far as I saw. So is there a better solution? Or a shorter, more elegant one?

or is it considered a standart behaviour from compilers to remove blocks of such if statements as a compile time optimization?

Make a function with the #ifdef inside it. if the function doesn't do anything it will be optimized out. Demo : https://godbolt.org/z/176ne4Yo3

Small update to the example : https://godbolt.org/z/Ghz63eEq6

Instead of C style #ifdefs in the proposed function, you can use if constexpr (with C++17 onwards).

@wohlstad though skipping the dead branch only works in templates, which might come as a surprise

@463035818_is_not_an_ai why can't we use constexpr bool cond = true;  if constexpr (cond) { ... } else { ... } in a non-template context (and expect the compiler to eliminate the dead branch) ? From my little assembly understanding it seems to work - see here.

@wohlstad you can, but the false branch is not guaranteed to be ignored. Example: https://godbolt.org/z/Gj6KvK1PW. I don't think it matters for what OP plans to do, until it does and then it comes as a surprise ;)   (the optimizer may still remove it though)

@463035818_is_not_an_ai I agree the false branch is not ignored in the sense that it must be valid compilation-wise. But from the point of view of performance I think it is equivalent to an #ifdef (which is what seems to bother the OP since they mention "overhead").

@wholstad sure, but that you get with a plain if already. Branch prediction works quite well and a const bool Debug; is easy to predict

@463035818_is_not_an_ai With a plain if you can have some minimal overhead if the condition evaluation and branching code is not eliminated (although you might argue that any sane optimizer will optimize it out ... and I will agree with that ;-) ). And I just saw also your mention of branch predicition.

A function with empty guts is not good enough because its parameters will still have to be evaluated (e.g. log("the size of {} is {}", getArray(), getArray.size()). To eliminate all the overhead, log needs to be a macro (yikes).


I am looking for an elegant and short solution to make the logging lines present or not present based on a parameter.

Making a function log_text() and then placing macro check inside the function is a suboptimal solution:
void log_text(std::string_view text){
#ifdef _DEBUG
//...
#endif
}
//...
log_text("tree size: "s + std::to_string(tree.calculate_size()) + "\n");

In this example, the call to calculate_size() can't be optimized away.
Base macro functionality for what you want (with zero optimizer assumptions) is very simple:
#ifdef _DEBUG //the name should be defined in makefile, not in C++ code
#define LOG(text) utils::log_text(__FILE__, __LINE__, __func__, text)
#else
#define LOG(text)
#endif

If you're using C++20, use std::source_location instead of __FILE__ and such (thanks to Red.Wave for pointing that out).
However, this solution is somewhat unstable: sooner or later you'll want some texts logged in release. Making LOG_DEBUG() and LOG_RELEASE() is a suboptimal solution since then you'll likely want more precise level tuning. But as another dynamic, once someone's done with debugging a specific module, they tend to leave excess diagnostic logging. The result is slow cluttering of the  log on every output level.
So, you'll want to rely on optimizer removing checks that are false at compile-time and organize such checks in a developer-friendly way. Below is one possible idea how to do so.
Lazy evaluation
C++ has three operators with lazy evaluation: ||, && and ?:. So, we can write this:
#define LOG(lv) (lv)<util::log_level ? util::null_stream : \
  util::log_stream(__FILE__, __LINE__, __func__)

where util::log_stream returns a stream object of the same type as util::null_stream. While this can fail in some tricky scenarios, normally as long as both lv and util::log_level are compile-time constants, optimizer should eliminate the entirety of the second clause when the condition is true:
LOG(Trace) << "tree size: " << tree.calculate_size() << std::endl;

will not call calculate_size() needlessly now.
Module-dependent logging
To avoid log clutter described above, we want to allow changing of logging threshold module-wise while still keeping it a compile-time constant. One can do so via function overloading:
inline constexpr LogLevel log_module_level(uint16_t){
#ifdef _DEBUG
  return LogLevel::Info;
#else
  return LogLevel::Warning;
#endif
}

#define LOG_MODULE_LEVEL(lv) \
  inline static constexpr LogLevel log_module_level(int){ return lv; }

#define LOG(lv) (lv)<log_module_level(0) ? util::null_stream : \
  util::log_stream(__FILE__, __LINE__, __func__)


Now one can always write LOG_MODULE_LEVEL in a module they're debugging, be as verbose as they like and simply comment that one line in the end.
C++20+ non-macro alternative
C++20 provides std::source_location to replace macros like __FILE__ and we have lambdas for lazy evaluation of function arguments. With those, you can make a macro-free logger version, albeit with a less readable syntax:
template<int>
inline static constexpr LogLevel log_level(void){
#ifdef _DEBUG
  return LogLevel::Info;
#else
  return LogLevel::Warning;
#endif
}

inline void log_text(const LogLevel lv,
                     const std::function<std::string(void)> txt,
                     const LogLevel currentLv = log_level<0>(),
                     const std::source_location l = std::source_location::current()){
  if constexpr(lv >= currentLv){ //gets eliminated at compile-time
    std::string output = txt();
    //...
  }
}

Usage:
//override global log level:
namespace utils {
template<> inline /*static*/ constexpr LogLevel log_level<0>(void){ 
  return LogLevel::Trace;
}
}
//...
//use
utils::log_text(LogLevel::Trace, [=](){
  return "tree size: "s + std::to_string(tree.calculate_size()) + "\n"
});


I strongly trust that the times of c macros in c++ are over! Instead you can trust that empty functions will removed by the optimizer. I suggest to use a simple template which can be specialized to do something and to do nothing.


A call to a function whose definition isn't available can't be optimized away (since it can have observable side effects, optimizer isn't allowed to change the code from "calling" to "non-calling"). You have to build expressions where the call isn't evaluated. Technically you can wrap it in a lambda but without yet another macro the resulting syntax becomes cumbersome. 2) In the specific case of logging, usually you want __FILE__ and __LINE__. I don't know any way to use them implicitly without a macro and believe such a way doesn't exist.


I have a totally different concern. Disabling logging to have no overhead, implies that enabling loging does incur overhead. Often that is not desirable, for example when you try to reconstruct a bug and suddenly logging makes that small difference in time that makes the bug not appear. Though, OP asked for it.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai I'm not sure it can be fixed. When I try to reconstruct a bug, I usually need to add some more logging - which may lead to different optimizations for the rest of the code no matter what I do (and especially so when the code has a sneaky UB). But I agree that this is something to keep in mind.

Don't use __FILE__ and __LINE anymore. std::source_location gives you all you want. Learn to use defaulted parameters.

@Red.Wave Thanks for pointing this one out. Added an attempt at non-macro solution although it still looks bad to me.

log_point::log_point(source_lication=current()); then void log_point::log(auto&&...args)const&&; next log_point{}.log("format {} {} {}"sv, x, y, z); this design captures the source location in constructor of an rvalue, and forwards it to the log destination. There's more to do, but I leave it there. Another option is to have log as a free function: void log(log_point const && lg, auto&&...args); next: log({}, "format {} {} {}", x, y, z); this has less syntactic noise.
